# Sitecore 7.2 MVC links are not rendering properly

Tags: sitecore, sitecore7, sitecore7.2, sitecore-mvc

I am using MVC for sitecore 7.2 website, I have a rich html field called body and has links to other sitecore content items.

output HTML for the links is rendered something like this

```
http://mysite/mypage/~/~/link.aspx?_id=6D705F2DED874D21A1367CB0F4A2F58D&_z=z
```

I am trying to render actual URL of the content item.

I have tried this but not working for me.

`@Html.Sitecore().Field("Body")`

I have also tried this but it is getting render as plain text

`@Editable(GlassItem, x => x.Body)`

Do I need to so some configuration changes??

Comment: In you web.config or config patches check te value of <setting name="Media.MediaLinkPrefix" value=""/>  default = empty means ~/ for Sitecore 7.2

Comment: yes it is empty but this settings is for media items only, has it got something to do with sitecore items?

Comment: Do you have the 'ExpandLinks' processor in the 'renderField' pipeline? I believe that one is responsible for resolving the links you mention.

Comment: I did not add or remove any processor.

Comment: Not saying you did, but in general you try to exclude possibilities when solving problems. I'd recommend checking out /sitecore/admin/showconfig.aspx and see if the processor is present.

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me.

```
@Html.Raw(Sitecore.Links.LinkManager.ExpandDynamicLinks(Sitecore.Context.Item.Fields["Body"].Value))
```